# Translating Keymaps to Ex Commands

Tags: key-bindings, ex-mode

Say that I have some semi-complex keymaps like the following:

```
nnoremap <Leader>s :%s/\s\+$//e
nnoremap <Leader>u mz:r!uuidgen<CR>dW"_dd`zp"
nnoremap <Leader>d g/\v"([^"]|\n)*"\ze\n\s*\[.*\]/normal gngq
```

In general, how does one translate an arbitrary keymap to a VimL function?

The following does not work:

```
function! Trim()
  normal mz:%s/\s\+$//e<cr>`z
endfunction
command! Trim call Trim()

function! UUID()
  normal mz:r!uuidgen<CR>dW"_dd`zp
endfunction
command! UUID call UUID()

function! FormatClojureDocStrings()
  normal mz:g/\v"([^"]|\n)*"\ze\n\s*\[.*\]/normal gngq<cr>`z
endfunction
command! FormatClojureDocStrings call FormatClojureDocStrings()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because special keys like `<esc>` are not translated to their actual meaning in normal commands.  Thus, `normal <esc>` translates to literally typing `less-than e s c greater-than`.  You can get around this by doing something like this:

```
execute "normal <esc>"
```

In your case, it would look like this:

```
function! Trim()
  execute "normal mz:%s/\s\+$//e<cr>`z"
endfunction
command! Trim call Trim()

function! UUID()
  execute "normal mz:r!uuidgen<CR>dW\"_dd`zp"
endfunction
command! UUID call UUID()

function! FormatClojureDocStrings()
  execute "normal mz:g/\v\"([^\"]|\n)*\"\ze\n\s*\[.*\]/normal gngq<cr>`z"
endfunction
command! FormatClojureDocStrings call FormatClojureDocStrings()
```

Note that these special keys will only be translated if they are in double quotes.

Comment: Do the quotes inside of the execute strings need to be escaped?

Comment: Yes they do, forgot to include that.

Answer (score 4):

Typically you divide your commands up into 3 categories:

- Normal commands that need to run via `:normal`/`:normal!`
- Ex-commands which can be run without  the leading `:`
- Commands that need to "built up" use `execute`. e.g. `execute "s/" . pat . "/". rep . "/g"`. (This is actually just a specialization of the previous rule)

Lets take a do a quick-n-dirty attempt at your UUID command:

```
command! UUID call s:uuid()
function s:uuid()
  normal! mz
  r!uuidgen
  normal! dW"_dd`zp
endfunction
```

Now we have a few issues with this:

- We are mutating the `z` mark and the unnamed register so this may cause surprises. The typical solution is to save the register and restore the register later in the function
- Ex-commands typically do things linewise so this command is a bit out of the ordinary. (This may be better as a mapping `<c-r><c-u>` perhaps)

Fixing/side-stepping the mutation issues by using the expression register, `"=,` and the `system()` function.

```
command! UUID execute "normal! a\<c-r>=substitute(system('uuidgen'), '\\n', '', '')\<cr>\<esc>"
```

For more help see:

```
:h :normal
:h :execute
:h i_ctrl-r
:h system(
```

You may also want to look at Steve Losh's [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/).